# Jenkins iOS Build Provisioning profile Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration, auto-build

When I try to build the iOS Application from jenkins its showing the error as below in console log

> FATAL: The path to store mobile provisioning profile files on the
>   master is not configured. Go the plugin main configuration page and
>   give the path. java.io.IOException: The path to store mobile
>   provisioning profile files on the master is not configured. Go the
>   plugin main configuration page and give the path.     at
>   com.sic.plugins.kpp.KPPProvisioningProfilesBuildWrapper.copyProvisioningProfiles(KPPProvisioningProfilesBuildWrapper.java:142)
>     at
>   com.sic.plugins.kpp.KPPProvisioningProfilesBuildWrapper.setUp(KPPProvisioningProfilesBuildWrapper.java:99)
>     at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:156)  at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
>     at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)  at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)   at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
>     at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:408) Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 1):

You must configure the provisioning profile directory if you want to build the project on the `master` branch.The path is:`/Users/{username}/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It pretty much tells you what to do:

> Go the plugin main configuration page and give the path [to store mobile provisioning profile]

Comment: we can see that but it's better to show where to add the path